# SSIS runs a package multiple times in parallel

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a package that does a job with the configuration from a table.

right now I can create a [foreach loop] and it will work fine and do the process for each row.
but since it will run in serial and my processes are independent I want my [foreach loop] runs all of the packages in parallel. 
does anyone know how to do that?

(image for visualization so don't mind the red errors)

[image]

Comment: I've created a config driven master package and it worked well, but the only way I could get things running in parallel was to put multiple execute package tasks within the Foreach Loop container, and include logic to disable the ones that weren't needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to get that to work with a Exec SQL statement. As soon as the SQL fires successfully and starts the package then it moves to the next loop.

```
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'Package.dtsx',
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT,
    @folder_name=N'Deployed Projects',
      @project_name=N'Integration Services Project1',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
      @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,
    @object_type=50,
      @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
      @parameter_value=@var0
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO
```

Here's the Microsoft link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-run-tsql-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

Setting parameters uses a different object type that you need to google.

Comment: it kinda works!
because then I don't have clean SSIS report and history.
so i consider it as impossible.